# sparql - replace triple with union of triples

Tags: java, sparql, jena

Below is a simple sparql query from lubm.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ub: <http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#>
SELECT ?X  ?Y1  ?Y2  ?Y3
WHERE
{?X rdf:type ub:Professor .}
```

And there is a `Map<String,List<String>>` which contains some sub-class data inferred from SCHEMA like

```
{
    "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#Professor>":[
        "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#Chair>",
        "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#Dean>",
        "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#AssistantProfessor>",
        ....
    ]
}
```

I want to replace this triple `?X rdf:type ub:Professor .` in that sparql query with union of its sub-classes like:

```
{{{{?X a <http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#Professor>}
    UNION
   {?X a <http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#Chair>}
  }
   UNION
  {?X a <http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#Dean>}
 }
  UNION
 {?X a <http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench-dl.owl#AssistantProfessor>}
}
```

but I have no idea how can I do this specific thing.

Could you please provide me some code to do this in jena(java)...?

Thanks with gratitude:)

Comment: The UNION syntax isn't limited to 2 sub-patterns: you can have `{ UI } UNION { U2 } UNION { U3 } UNION { U4 }`

Comment: Is your question how to modify the query after it has been parsed? Using Jena's `QueryBuilder` you could build a new query. Or create a string and parse it. Or run `ElementTransform` to edit a query to produce a new one.

Comment: @AndyS yes, after `Query query = QueryFactory.read(queryFile);`.
I've got some clues from documentation.
I'm  trying to create a new query use `Element` based on the documentation of [jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/manipulating_sparql_using_arq.html) now.

Comment: As Andy said, either create the string and parse it or modify the existing `Query` object

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question in this way:

Use the sub-class data to create a `ElementUnion` and add it to the `Element` of the `query`.

```
Query query = QueryFactory.read(queryFile);
ElementGroup element = (ElementGroup) query.getQueryPattern();
Triple pattern1 = Triple.create(Var.alloc("s1"), Var.alloc("p1"), Var.alloc("o1"));
Triple pattern2 = Triple.create(Var.alloc("s2"), Var.alloc("p2"), Var.alloc("o2"));
ElementTriplesBlock block1 = new ElementTriplesBlock(); 
ElementTriplesBlock block2 = new ElementTriplesBlock(); 
block1.addTriple(pattern1);                             
block2.addTriple(pattern2);                             
ElementUnion eu = new ElementUnion();
eu.addElement(block1);
eu.addElement(block2);
element.addElement(eu);
```

After I figured out how to create `ElementUnion`, this problem was solved.